# How and when linux scan MBR and GPT?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have a some problem with device reconizing at te system boot time. I have tried to get some information with udev_log="debug" - no success. It's looks like that udev works on data has been built by some other process.

So, is there a way to debug a process of scanning MBR and GPT during system startup ?

This is under Ubuntu 16.x-18.x, kernel 4.4-4.15.

Comment: Have you looked at the bootloader (grub and its kind)? It's what does the first crack on the disk recognition.

Comment: GRUB scanning MBR/EBR for preparing booting options. It's not a matter of my interest.

Comment: Then, the disk driver(s) in the kernel (enable early printk ...)

Comment: Can u provide references  to how to do this ?

Comment: Actually, normal kernel prints should be enough. What is the problem exactly? some partition mot detected?  Whole device not detected?

Comment: Yes, second partition is not recognized.